# Expo.js: Capture event when my app goes into the background?

Tags: react-native, expo

If I'm using my app and then switch out of it using the home button, app switcher, etc, Is there a way to reliably run some code when this event is detected? I want to do some tasks such as cancelling timers, scheduling notifications, and so on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can track app's state using `AppState` provided by 'react-native'

By using `AppState.currentState` you will know whether the app is in *foreground*, *background*, *active* or *inactive*. If you want to perform some tasks whenever the state changes you can use event listeners provided by `AppState`.

You can add the following logic in your Component to get it done -

```
componentDidMount() {
  AppState.addEventListener('change', this.handleStateChange);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  AppState.removeEventListener('change', this.handleStateChange);
}
```

`handleStateChange` will be called every time the app moves from foreground to background or vice-versa with the app's current state passed as an argument.

For further reference see the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate)

Hope it helped.